# symmetric difference is equal to its negation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So I have a problem I have to give 2 proofs for the following:

$$A \oplus B = A' \oplus B'$$

so the first proof needs to be with what they call "set algebra" which I think I did correctly.

$(A-B)∪(B-A)=(A′-B′)∪(B′-A′)$

$(A∩B′)∪(B∩A′)=(A′∩B′′)∪(B′∩A′′)$

$(A∩B′)∪(B∩A′)=(A′∩B)∪(B′∩A)$

$(A∩B′)∪(B∩A′)=(B∩A′)∪(A∩B′)$

The problem is the second proof which is showing that some variable x is a subset of both the sides. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $x$ is a subset of both sides or that it is an element of both sides?  The usual approach is to show that an arbitrary element on one side is also an element on the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin {align}x \in A \oplus B &\iff (x \in A \wedge x \in B') \vee (x \in A' \wedge x \in B)\\ &\iff (x \in A' \wedge x \in B) \vee (x \in A \wedge x \in B')\\ &\iff (x \in A' \wedge x \in B'') \vee (x \in A'' \wedge x \in B')\\ &\iff x \in A' \oplus B'\end {align}$$

Comment: I don't see your last step how you go from (x∈A′∧x∈B)∨(x∈A∧x∈B) to x∈A′⊕B′ this or your first step how you get rid of the A' from the second side.

Comment: The first step is just the definition of symmetric difference.  It has all the elements that are in A and not in B plus those that are in B and not in A.  The last step is the same with the roles of A,A' and B,B' reversed except I missed a prime on the last B.  I have added a step.

Answer (score 0):

If $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of a set $A$, then 
$$\chi_{A\Delta B} = |\chi_A - \chi_B| = |(1-\chi_A) - (1-\chi_B)| = |\chi_{A'} - \chi_{B'}|= \chi_{A'\Delta B'}|$$

We have used the standard notation $A \Delta B$ for the symmetric difference of sets.

Comment: Not that it changes the proof much, but $\chi_{A\Delta B} = |\chi_A - \chi_B|\;$ is rather unusual in boolean algebra. Straight from the definitions that would be $\chi_{A\Delta B} = \chi_A + \chi_B - 2 \chi_A\; \chi_B\;$.